# Error while uploading a image in firebase in android studio in java

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        reference = rootNode.getReference("User");

        // Get all the values
        String name = Objects.requireNonNull(regName.getEditText()).getText().toString().trim();
        String email = Objects.requireNonNull(regEmail.getEditText()).getText().toString().trim();
        String phoneNo = Objects.requireNonNull(regPhone.getEditText()).getText().toString().trim();
        String password = Objects.requireNonNull(regPass.getEditText()).getText().toString().trim();
        String address = Objects.requireNonNull(regAddress.getEditText()).getText().toString().trim();

        int genderId = gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        String gender = (genderId == R.id.radioButtonMale) ? "Male" : "Female";

        String college = autoCompleteTextCollege.getText().toString().trim();
        String year = autoCompleteTextYear.getText().toString().trim();
        String department = autoCompleteTextDept.getText().toString().trim();
        String division = autoCompleteTextDivision.getText().toString().trim();
        String batch = autoCompleteTextBatch.getText().toString().trim();

        // Check if any field is empty
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNo) ||
                TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || TextUtils.isEmpty(address) || TextUtils.isEmpty(gender) ||
                TextUtils.isEmpty(college) || TextUtils.isEmpty(year) || TextUtils.isEmpty(department) ||
                TextUtils.isEmpty(division) || TextUtils.isEmpty(batch)) {

            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "All fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }


        UserHelperClass helperClass = new UserHelperClass(name,email,password,phoneNo,address,gender,college,year,department,division,batch);
        reference.child(phoneNo).setValue(helperClass);

        String userID = phoneNo;

        StorageReference profilePhotoRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profile_photo/"+userID+".jpg");

        if (filePath != null){
            profilePhotoRef.putFile(filePath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            profilePhotoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    String profilePhotoUrl = uri.toString();
                                    helperClass.setProfilePhotoUrl(profilePhotoUrl);

                                    if (collegeIdFilePath != null){
                                        StorageReference collegeIdPhotoRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("collegeIdPhotos").child(userID + ".jpg");
                                        collegeIdPhotoRef.putFile(collegeIdFilePath)
                                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                            collegeIdPhotoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                                    String collegeIdPhotoUrl = uri.toString();
                                                                    helperClass.setCollegeIdPhotoUrl(collegeIdPhotoUrl);

                                                                    reference.child(userID).setValue(helperClass);

                                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                                                                    startActivity(i);
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                })
                                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"College ID card photo uploade fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"College ID card Not selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Profile photo upload fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
});
```

I have written this code for inserting images taken during user registration. However, it is giving me an error that says '**Profile photo upload failed.**' I used Java for Android Studio, and the database used is Firebase Database.

Expected the code that can able to handle the image insertion into firebase using java in android studio

Answer (score 1):

When a `Task` fails, it contains an exception with more information about the cause of that failure. Log that exception to learn more:

```
...
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.e("Upload", "Upload failed", e); // 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"College ID card photo uploade fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```